# OS Installation

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, operating-systems

What happens internally when we install an OS like Ubuntu?
Want to "understand" the complete how-and-what of installing an OS like Ubuntu.
Any online tutorial or link?

Comment: The installer itself gives a pretty good indication of what each step is for and what it is doing. Can you be more specific about what you're after?

Answer (score 3):

The salient operations for an OS installation on a PC are:

- allocate and format disk partitions on the mass storage device (e.g. a hard disk drive);
- create a filesystem and swap area;
- examine and determine system hardware: construct a device tree and    associate drivers for each device;
- read from CD/DVD and/or download files, then unpack/extract and write to the new filesystem the appropriate system binaries, scripts, configuration files, utilities, applications etc.
- setup appropriate services, e.g. networking and timekeeping.

These operations have chicken & egg relationships, so the execution is not straightforward.